# Ajax works locally but not when website is deployed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have written some jQuery code that works fine locally but always ends up not working when I upload it to my server. For example: on my website fearlessmovement.se/kalas when you click on the input field where the placeholder says "Antal personer", it is supposed to increment a column in the database. Running the code locally works and does increment the value in the database (the database is not local).

jQuery code with ajax:

```
function saveClick() {
    antalP.click(function () {
        if (clicked === false) {
    //this is to only make it run once
            clicked = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://fearlessmovement.se/saveClick.php"})
                    .done(function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The php code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `clicks`";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$save = 0;



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$save = $row['click'];
echo $save;
}

$increment = $save + 1;

$query1 = "UPDATE `clicks` SET click=$increment";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

mysqli_close($con);
```

As I mentioned before, the code works perfectly when I run it locally. Is it that my server is blocking the ajax requests? The worst part is that it works some times, something like once every five minutes.

Comment: can you figure out which part is working and which is not? Any Errormessages? Does it hit the php at all? DB-Connection successful?

Comment: For starters the simplest test is open that url in browser....does php work? Then inspect actual ajax request in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: Sometimes it does update the database, so it works maybe once every 5 minutes. When I check the network tab, two post requests are logged opposed to one request when I run the code locally. It first says saveClick.php 302 found text/html, then the next request is saveClick 200 OK xhr

Comment: is saveClick.php in the right folder? is there any .htaccess ReWrite happening?

Comment: Thanks @jeff 
I deleted all the contents of my htaccess and now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem** was my .htaccess which looked like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://fearlessmovement.se/404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
## Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

I guess it had something to do with the rewriting of the file endings, such as removing .php from the url which would make calls to saveClick instead of saveClick.php.

**Solution:** I commented everything out in my .htaccess and my ajax request works!

Thank you for the tip Jeff.

Comment: You're welcome! I saw it when calling the php-script directly.

Comment: You mean when writing fearlessmovement.se/saveClick.php?

Comment: @Jeff do you know how I could change my current .htaccess to still rewrite the urls but skip certain urls?

Comment: 1st question: yes, just copied the url into browser. 2nd Question: sorry, I'm not a .htaccess crack